# menu parent-child hover - stop animation - jquery

Tags: jquery, animation, navigation, hover, parent-child

I have this example here: http://jsfiddle.net/QRChv/

Im trying to set it up so that when you hover over a child list item, its animation will start, but the parent doesnt invoke its `.hover()` function.

I dont know if this can be done, but is there a way to stop the parent from actually going through with its animation. So it wont actually do anything when its child list item is being hovered over.

I have a bunch of if statements setup for each list item, tried to keep it simple.

Comment: $(this).parent().unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');

ive tried adding that, but no luck.

http://jsfiddle.net/QRChv/5/

Comment: thanks @jAndy and @rcravens. the last issue that i commented on was fixable via css. http://jsfiddle.net/QRChv/17/

I do see an issue if someone were to have a similar navigation but if the elements were right next to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated your code:

http://jsfiddle.net/QRChv/4/

You need to stop event propagation, i.e. by returning `false` from the handler.

You could also call `.stopPropagation()` yourself on the `event object`

Comment: thanks, i noticed that if i hover on the first list item and then on to the second list item, the first will not animate to its original color.

I need to read up on event propagation, because im not sure what that is

Comment: @NilsR: Yes do that. In simple words, all events do "bubble up" in the `DOM tree`. So a `mouseover` event happening in a nested element will bubble up to all parent nodes, unless you explicitly cancel that. This is wat `.stopPropagation` does.

Answer (score 1):

What about adding a call to stopPropagation. Something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/rcravens/QRChv/9/

Comment: thanks that worked for the most part. :] But if i hover over the first element then straight to the second, the first does not animate back.